# How to explicitly specify that a name refers to a variable, rather than a column name, in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following chunk of code:

```
gap <- 1000  

HCE <- HCE %>%
   dplyr::mutate(ordered = gap * (as.numeric(outcome) - 1) + original)
```

I want to dismbiguate, in the mutate directive, that gap refers to the variable, not to a "gap" column. How can I do so?

Comment: With variable you mean an object in the enclosing environment? Then use `.env$gap`. Alternatively, we can use `get()` and specify the environment in  the `.envir` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.data` and `.env` pronouns make it explicit where to find objects when programming with data-masked functions.

```r
HCE %>%
  mutate(ordered = .env$gap * (as.numeric(outcome) - 1) + original)
```

Or use the [injection operator](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/injection-operator.html) `!!`:

```r
HCE %>%
  mutate(ordered = !!gap * (as.numeric(outcome) - 1) + original)
```

###### Reference

1. [Injection operator `!!`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/injection-operator.html)
2. [Injecting env-variables with `!!`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask-ambiguity.html#injecting-env-variables-with-)

Comment: injection operator?

Comment: @StefanoBorini Yes, you could search the reference links

Comment: @Greg so using it in my context as written above is the equivalent of slapping the actual value of gap in there? e.g. if I had `gap <- 3`, writing that mutate would be strictly equivalent to writing `mutate(ordered  = 3 * (as.numeric...)`?

Comment: @StefanoBorini You have the right idea, but I made a mistake in my example.  You can indeed inject literal values and even functions!  However, when putting the injected value to the left of an assignment, you must use `:=` instead of `=`, like so: `x <- as.symbol("hello")` and then `mutate(!!x := 1)` is equivalent to `mutate(hello = 1)`; while `y <- 3` and then `mutate(new_col = !!y)` is equivalent to `mutate(new_col = 3)`.

Comment: @StefanoBorini As for strict equivalence, there are exceptions when injection behaves counterintuitively, due to scopes and to the interpretations of injection operators themselves.  But for **`dplyr`** purposes, the equivalence should be pretty strict.

Comment: @StefanoBorini So in short: "yes".  Injection is like _"slapping the actual value of `gap` in there"_.  There are simply a few cases (like `:=`) that need more nuanced consideration.

Comment: @Greg I swear this language is completely impenetrable. Too many operators flying around and interacting in illogical ways.

Comment: @StefanoBorini In all fairness, such ["unquotation"](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#unquoting) is part of "tidy evaluation", which is [a framework unto itself](https://rlang.r-lib.org/#frameworks). It overloads some existing operators (especially [`!!`](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#the-polite-fiction-of)) to permit programmatic manipulation of the R language _itself_. So this is a fairly specialized situation, for use by fairly advanced R programmers.